# Is it efficient to use Cucumber Datatables when lot of test data has to be created

Tags: automation, cucumber, cucumber-java

I have to automate the scenarios that require lot of pre-Req data before verification of expected results.
For Example
**Scenario: Scenario1

When I add Data for Order of type 1

|name | Quantity| values|

|A    |1        | 2     |

And I add Data for Order of type 2

|name | Quantity| values|UOM    |

|A    |1        | 2     |    mg   |

And I add Data for Order of type 3

|name | Quantity| values|UOM    |Deliver|

|A    |1        | 2     |    mg   |Home|**

Can I use datatables for each Order creation steps. Will it be efficient to use datatable or i should use list.

Answer (score 1):

When cuking you should not put your data in your feature files. Instead you should name your data and refer to the data in your feature files by using the name.

You can then define your data in code in your step definitions, (or better still in a helper method).

This allows you to write features that focus on WHAT you are doing and WHY that is important, rather than on HOW you are doing something.

If you aren't interested in expressing WHAT you are doing and WHY its important you should probably not bother using Cucumber and use a unit testing tool instead. Its much easier to deal with complex data in unit tests because unit tests are written in code, so you can easily do things like

- import data from elsewhere
- use loops to construct data
- use structures to define data
- ...